# Size of parametric plane in gnuplot

Tags: plot, geometry, gnuplot, points, plane

I want to plot a series of points, a plane and the intersection points with that plane using gnuplot. In order to do this, I created the following gnuplot script:

```
set title 'Homogeneous field with plane intersection'
set xlabel 'x'
set ylabel 'y'
set zlabel 'z'
set parametric
splot 'points.txt' with linespoints, 'intersectionPoints.txt' with points
pointtype 7 lc rgb 'red',
60 + 0 * u, u, v
```

The script produces the following plot:
[image]

Everything works fine, however the size of the parametric plane is way too small. How can I get gnuplot to automatically adjust the size of the plane to roughly match the dimensions of the rest of the plot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set the ranges for the two parameters `u` and `v`, for example

```
set urange [-50:250]
set vrange [-20:20]
```

From `help parametric`: " Currently the default range for these parametric variables is [-5:5].  Setting the ranges to something more meaningful is expected.".

Comment: Alright, thank you very much. For everyone reading this I managed to find a way to make gnuplot "sort of" adjust the ranges depending on the dimensions. Just add
`set vrange [GPVAL_Z_MIN:GPVAL_Z_MAX]
set urange [GPVAL_Y_MIN:GPVAL_Y_MAX]` after your `splot` statement and then add `replot`. This will adjust the ranges for you.